# how to populate dynamic content in select options in drupal web forms

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm trying to populate dynamic content in the select options like depending upon the **country** it should populate **Country** related **states**. I want this thing to be done by using web forms only.

I'm Using `Drupal-7.60` Version.

Can we able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use any one module from below list. It will helpful in your case

1) https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_term_opts
2) https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional

Comment: need to install both?

Comment: both are not working Giving error while adding second select option

Answer (score 1):

My best option is to use the `hook_webform_select_options_info()` to define a callback that can be used as select list options as bellow :

```
function mymodule_webform_select_options_info() {
  $items = array();

  $items['my_dynamic_custom_options'] = array(
    'title' => t('My dynamic custom options'),
    'options callback' => '_get_dynamic_custom_options',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Then you need to provide the function for the callbacks that you specified above :

```
function _get_dynamic_custom_options() {
  // Get your options based on the logic you wants.
  // For example you can get options based on a taxonomy vocabulary terms.
  $options = array();
  $options['key'] = 'value';
  return $options;
}
```

**Usage :**

Clear your caches, and in your webform, under :
("Form Components" > "Select options". > "Add" > "Load a pre-built options list"),
you'll find the option 'My dynamic custom options' defined above.

Hope this will help you.